# How to display selected item of database table into an empty table of the same database

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.6

I have two tables named Test and Save_Test..Test table has one column with five values and Save_Test table has one column with no values..I need to create save button in such a way that when I select a value from Test table and click on save button it should get stored in Save_Test table..Each time when I click the save button,previously stored value in save_Test table should be replaced with the new selected value of Test table..Here is my code..Please help..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600" initialize="application1_initializeHandler(event)">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            import mx.collections.ArrayList;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;
            import mx.events.ValidationResultEvent;
            import mx.rpc.AsyncResponder;
            import mx.rpc.AsyncToken;
            import mx.rpc.events.FaultEvent;
            import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;
            import mx.rpc.soap.WebService;
            private var web:WebService;
            private var list:ArrayList = new ArrayList();

            protected function application1_initializeHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                web = new WebService();
                web.wsdl = "https://www.geoviewer8.com/gv8webservices/CSF_NewGVOConfig/GVOConfig.asmx?wsdl";
                web.loadWSDL();
                var s:String = "SELECT * FROM [CSFTestNew].[dbo].[Test]";
                var t:AsyncToken = web.GetRec("[Test]", s, "1", "SQLExpress");
                t.addResponder(new AsyncResponder(onResult, onFault, t));
            }
            protected function onResult(event:ResultEvent, token:Object=null):void
            {
                if(event.result.GetRecResult.Tables != null)
                {
                    for each(var table:Object in event.result.GetRecResult.Tables)
                    {
                        for each(var row:Object in table.Rows)
                        {
                            list.addItem(row);

                        }
                    }
                }

            }

            protected function onFault(event:FaultEvent, token:Object=null):void
            {
                trace(event.fault.toString());
            }

            private function validate(event):void
            {
                var p:String = "INSERT INTO [CSFTestNew].[dbo].[Save_Test]([Areas]) VALUES ('Apple','Banana','Mango','Grapes','StrawBerry')";   
                /* var event:ValidationResultEvent = validate(); */
            } 

            protected function btn_click(event:MouseEvent):void
            {

            } 

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:ComboBox id="cbareas" x="201" y="241" dataProvider="{list}" labelField="Areas"
                requireSelection="true" />
    <s:Button id="btn" x="417" y="243" label="Save" click="btn_click(event)" />   
</s:Application>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

While this may be a little late, I have just seen your question, your insert statement shows 5 values and only one field, your values should be 'apple, grape, orange...'

In essence what you are doing is trying to put 5 different columns of data into one column and sql does not work like that.

I use sql stored procedures and call them through cold fusion so that I don't get any potential sql injection issues.

You do no have any parameters and using a string through the URL leaves the door wide open for sql injection attacks.

Hope this helps.

Jim